# MongoDB data receive is too slow

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have documents with huge count of fields (7500 fields in each)
but fields values is simple data (numbers only), when i try to query Collection it works great (i look at mongo profiler and it use indexes correctly)
but it takes too long time to iterate cursor (to receive data)
count of resulting documents is ~450 but it takes about ~2 minutes tu receive all documents 
i already updated mongoDB version to last one, also updated MongoDB driver (for .NET), recreated indexes but nothing helps

P.S connection is not slow (BD server is in my local network - 100Base-T/Fast Ethernet)
Query Code example is below

```
        var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;

        var filter = builder.Eq("OrgID", orgID);
        filter = filter & builder.Eq("DateDeleted", (DateTime?)null);

        var collection = GetCollection("NameOfCollection");
        var result = collection.Find(filter);

        using (var cursor = result.ToCursor())
        {
            while (cursor.MoveNext())
            {
                var batch = cursor.Current;
                foreach (var document in batch)
                {
                    yield return document;
                }
            }
        }
```

and i have index for that fields separately and also there is composite index with both fields in one index

and it works great with collections where is much more documents but less fields (~20 fields in each document)

Comment: Perhaps you could show us the indexes on the collection, the model (if you're not using `BsonDocument`) and the code you're using to perform the query?

Comment: if the profiler is reporting a quick production of data, but your app is taking too long to retrieve it, it does suggest that either you have a terribly slow connection, or, your code could be improved.

Comment: No connection is not slow (DB server is in my local net 100Base Fast Ethernet)
Code example is below

var filter = builder.Eq("OrgID", orgID);
filter = filter & builder.Eq("DateDeleted", (DateTime?)null);

var collection = GetCollection([nameOfCollection]);
result = collection.Find(filter)
using (var cursor = result.ToCursor())
{
     while (cursor.MoveNext())
     {
          ......
     }
}

Comment: You should share some real document examples so people can try to reproduce

Comment: you can just create 6000 documents (with 7500 fields, length of each field name ~80)
insert that documents in collection and after that try find some of them :)
(e.g name of fields in my document looks like "dataContent_form01_tabCtrl05_tabPg10_group01_group03_table1000_tbx_col_12_row_30" and also there are some "system" fields like DateCreated (DateTime), DateDeleted (DateTime), OrganizationID (Guid), StatusID (Guid) and etc)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a cursor?  It is my understanding that fetches each record individually.  I bet if you iterated through the ToList() instead you’d get better performance because it’d fetch all the data in a single call.

```
Foreach(var batch in collection.Find(filter).ToList()){
    // your other code here
}
```

Also you are yielding the result which means that this is nested in an IEnumerable and whatever you are doing in between these retrieve calls can be slowing down the process, but you left that code out so it’s hard to say.

Comment: because ToList() is "memory leak"
see how works "yield return" and you understand why :)

Comment: I’d like you to explain to me how ToList() is a memory leak.  But if you want to skip ToList() to not iterate the list twice and defer allocation to the time of execution you can skip the Find(filter).ToList() and just iterate the Find(filter).  You response is kinda smug for someone who has a problem and doesn’t really know what’s going on.